# Normalization of categorical factor variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, normalization

For supervised machine learning for prediction, if I had some feature variables that are real, and also some features that are categorical--which have been coded using dummy variables (010, 001 etc)--I have normalized the real variables so that each of them sums to one. I am wondering what kind of a preprocessing I should do for the rest of the categorical features, before I run cross-validation routines and regression methods.

Comment: Why have you normalised the real ones to add to 1? I don't think you need to *normalise* the dummy ones.

Comment: I need a more concrete answer than an "I think"

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing categorical variables ought not have any real effect.